# parsing xml with LibXML Ruby truncates the data

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

**My Goal**: I want to grab every element named "SECTION" in the subject xml document; getting each SECTION, and everything under it.

**Constraint**: I must use LibXML Ruby; i.e., require 'xml'.

**Problem**: The output data is truncated.

**Questions (see output file1.xml)**:

- Why is the output in file1.xml truncated? Note: much of the text between the first 
  P(a)... /P tags (note: the truncation starts at the word "ethic...")
- Why has the code dropped the final two P elements (P(b)..., P(2)...)
  and the CITA element? What is causing ?xml version="1.0"
  encoding="UTF-8"? and SECTION/ to appear at the end of the output?

Note: output file2.xml has even more severe truncation. I'm including it in case it clarifies anything.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "xml"
reader = XML::Reader.file('infile2.xml')
while reader.read
  node = reader.node 
    if node.name == "SECTION"
      iteration = XML::Document.string(node.to_s)
      puts iteration
      puts "\n"
    end
end
```

The input file1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SECTION>
  <SECTNO>§ 0.735-1</SECTNO>
  <SUBJECT>Agency ethics officials.</SUBJECT>
  <P>(a) <E T="03">Designated Agency Ethics Official (DAEO).</E> The Assistant General Counsel (023) is the designated agency ethics official (DAEO) for the Department of Veterans Affairs. The Deputy Assistant General Counsel (023C) is the alternate DAEO, who is designated to act in the DAEO's absence. The DAEO has primary responsibility for the administration, coordination, and management of the VA ethics program, pursuant to 5 CFR 2638.201-204.</P>
  <P>(b) <E T="03">Deputy ethics officials.</E> (1) The Regional Counsel are deputy ethics officials. They have been delegated the authority to act for the DAEO within their jurisdiction, under the DAEO's supervision, pursuant to 5 CFR 2638.204.</P>
  <P>(2) The alternate DAEO, the DAEO's staff, and staff in the Offices of Regional Counsel, may also act as deputy ethics officials pursuant to delegations of one or more of the DAEO's duties from the DAEO or the Regional Counsel.</P>
  <CITA>[58 FR 61813, Nov. 23, 1993. Redesignated at 61 FR 11309, Mar. 20, 1996]</CITA>
</SECTION>
```

Output, given input file1.xml (above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SECTION>
  <SECTNO>§ 0.735-1</SECTNO>
  <SUBJECT>Agency ethics officials.</SUBJECT>
  <P>(a) <E T="03">Designated Agency Ethics Official (DAEO).</E> The Assistant General Counsel (023) is the designated agency ethics official (DAEO) for the Department of Veterans Affairs. The Deputy Assistant General Counsel (023C) is the alternate DAEO, who is designated to act in the DAEO's absence. The DAEO has primary responsibility for the administration, coordination, and management of the VA ethic</P></SECTION>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SECTION/>
```

The input file2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SUBPART>
  <HD SOURCE="HED">Subpart A—General Provisions</HD>
  <SECTION>
    <SECTNO>§ 0.735-1</SECTNO>
    <SUBJECT>Agency ethics officials.</SUBJECT>
    <P>(a) <E T="03">Designated Agency Ethics Official (DAEO).</E> The Assistant General Counsel (023) is the designated agency ethics official (DAEO) for the Department of Veterans Affairs. The Deputy Assistant General Counsel (023C) is the alternate DAEO, who is designated to act in the DAEO's absence. The DAEO has primary responsibility for the administration, coordination, and management of the VA ethics program, pursuant to 5 CFR 2638.201-204.</P>
    <P>(b) <E T="03">Deputy ethics officials.</E> (1) The Regional Counsel are deputy ethics officials. They have been delegated the authority to act for the DAEO within their jurisdiction, under the DAEO's supervision, pursuant to 5 CFR 2638.204.</P>
    <P>(2) The alternate DAEO, the DAEO's staff, and staff in the Offices of Regional Counsel, may also act as deputy ethics officials pursuant to delegations of one or more of the DAEO's duties from the DAEO or the Regional Counsel.</P>
    <CITA>[58 FR 61813, Nov. 23, 1993. Redesignated at 61 FR 11309, Mar. 20, 1996]</CITA>
  </SECTION>
  <SECTION>
    <SECTNO>§ 0.735-2</SECTNO>
    <SUBJECT>Government-wide standards.</SUBJECT>
    <P>For government-wide standards of ethical conduct and related responsibilities for Federal employees, see 5 CFR Part 735 and Chapter XVI.</P>
    <CITA>[61 FR 11309, Mar. 20, 1996. Redesignated at 63 FR 33579, June 19, 1998]</CITA>
  </SECTION>
</SUBPART>
```

Output, given input file2.xml (above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SECTION>
    <SECTNO>§ 0.735-1</SECTNO>
    <SUBJECT>Agency ethics officials.</SUBJECT>
    <P>(a) <E T="03">Designated Agency Ethics Official (DAEO).</E></P></SECTION>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SECTION/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SECTION>
    <SECTNO>§ 0.735-2</SECTNO>
    <SUBJECT>Government-wide standards.</SUBJECT>
    <P>For government-wide standards of ethical conduct and related responsibilities for Federal employees, see 5 CFR Part 735 and Chapter XVI.</P>
    <CITA/></SECTION>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SECTION/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the specific issue is, but I suspect it's related to the content not being just text, e.g., it contains nested nodes. Your best bet is to treat the document like XML, not like text.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I _thought_ I was treating the document like it is xml, but (obviously) am confused. Where is my thinking wrong? I'm trying to get the SECTION node(s), and everything, including any nested nodes and their content. -Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a huge XML document consider instead something like this:

```ruby
require "xml"
doc = XML::Document.file('infile1.xml')
doc.find('/SECTION').each do |s|
  puts "[#{s}]"
end
```

This outputs:

```xml
<SECTION>
  <SECTNO>§ 0.735-1</SECTNO>
  <SUBJECT>Agency ethics officials.</SUBJECT>
  <P>(a) <E T="03">Designated Agency Ethics Official (DAEO).</E> The Assistant General Counsel (023) is the designated agency ethics official (DAEO) for the Department of Veterans Affairs. The Deputy Assistant General Counsel (023C) is the alternate DAEO, who is designated to act in the DAEO's absence. The DAEO has primary responsibility for the administration, coordination, and management of the VA ethics program, pursuant to 5 CFR 2638.201-204.</P>
  <P>(b) <E T="03">Deputy ethics officials.</E> (1) The Regional Counsel are deputy ethics officials. They have been delegated the authority to act for the DAEO within their jurisdiction, under the DAEO's supervision, pursuant to 5 CFR 2638.204.</P>
  <P>(2) The alternate DAEO, the DAEO's staff, and staff in the Offices of Regional Counsel, may also act as deputy ethics officials pursuant to delegations of one or more of the DAEO's duties from the DAEO or the Regional Counsel.</P>
  <CITA>[58 FR 61813, Nov. 23, 1993. Redesignated at 61 FR 11309, Mar. 20, 1996]</CITA>
</SECTION>
```

This doesn't answer the question, instead it's a workaround.

I'm not sure what the actual issue with using a reader is, but I suspect it has something to do with it being cursor-ish. For example, the following works, delta there's still an additional empty section for the first XML document:

```ruby
if node.name == "SECTION"
  puts "#{reader.read_outer_xml}"
end
```

Comment: I'll report back if I figure out "the why" behind this behavior. Thank you for the workaround.